# Creating preset of function arguments in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to create preset of function arguments in Typescript?

For example:

```
type presetArgs = {val1: type1, val2: type2, val3: type3}

function someFunction(<presetArgs>): any {}
function someAnotherFunction(<presetArgs>): any {}
```

Comment: When you use the same argument structure multiple times, you should consider to wrap it into an object.

Comment: @Jozott Yes, sure, it's good solution to use one big object for couple of arguments. But in many cases traditional arguments list is needed.

Answer (score 2):

One simple way to annotate this would be to type [the rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) with a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple):

```
type FnArgs = [foo: number, bar: string];

function fn(...args: FnArgs) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
type PresetArgs = [string, number]

declare function f(...args: PresetArgs): void

f('x', 1) // OK
f() // Expected 2 arguments, but got 0.
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgThAzhYBBOBzRUC8UDaiwcAlgHYYA0UZArgLYBGEcAugFDsAmEAxgDYBDBFABmtMr2AkA9mTEAKAHQrhWAFywEyNJkQBKTQDcZJLp1EKA5AA8r1AIz6oAehdQA8gGl2l526gAURtIKQguKAAmKDUGCDJgRGpGWmAoDBk0gAYlIA)

Answer (score 0):

Rest parameters is a good idea but I'm not a great fan of having to do this:

```
const foo = args[0]
const bar = args[1]
```

This could work too:

```
type FunctionType = (foo: string, bar: number) => unknown

// function someFunction(foo: string, bar: number): string
const someFunction: FunctionType = (foo, bar) => {
    return 'something'
}
```